# How to copy a number and insert it to every 5th row?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to loop the `ACC_YEAR` from 1900 to 2501 for every 1500 row and then the `EARNED_MONTH` increment by 1 to 5.

As seen from the screenshot it stops at 1901. I want to add 1902, 1903 to 2501. Then the earned month should repeat from 1,2,3,4,5 based on the `ACC_YEAR`. Example :

[image: SQL Question]

Comment: Images of data are very poorly received. This seems like what you're after is a tally to create the years, and then a simply `CROSS JOIN`ing those rows with the numbers 1-5 . Have you tried anything to solve this? Please do show us what you've tried. If not, what research did you perform? Like I said, I suggest looking at a Tally@ [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/the-numbers-or-tally-table-what-it-is-and-how-it-replaces-a-loop-1)

Comment: Basically, i want to create two columns ACC_YEAR in which the year is from 1900 - 2501 in my database and the earned_month is 1 to 5. What i need help right now is , based on the ACC_YEAR, i want the earned month increase from 1 to 5. Then the next year repeat the pattern again from 1-5 up to year 2501. That's all i need. I am stuck with how to write the logic in SQL. Hence, i need help on this

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fbdf9/1)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable1 (ACC_YEAR int,UW_YEAR int, PROC_YEAR int)
CREATE TABLE MyTable2 (EARNED_MONTH int)

INSERT INTO MyTable1(ACC_YEAR,UW_YEAR,PROC_YEAR)
             VALUES (1900,1900,1900),
             (1900,1900,1900),
             (1900,1900,1900),
             (1900,1900,1900),
             (1900,1900,1900),
             (1901,1901,1901),
             (1901,1901,1901),
             (1901,1901,1901),
             (1901,1901,1901),
             (1901,1901,1901),
             (1902,1902,1902),
             (1902,1902,1902),
             (1902,1902,1902),
             (1902,1902,1902),
             (1902,1902,1902)

INSERT INTO MyTable2 (EARNED_MONTH) VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5)
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable1
CROSS JOIN MyTable2
GROUP BY ACC_YEAR,UW_YEAR,PROC_YEAR,EARNED_MONTH
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fbdf9/1/0)**:

```
| ACC_YEAR | UW_YEAR | PROC_YEAR | EARNED_MONTH |
|----------|---------|-----------|--------------|
|     1900 |    1900 |      1900 |            1 |
|     1900 |    1900 |      1900 |            2 |
|     1900 |    1900 |      1900 |            3 |
|     1900 |    1900 |      1900 |            4 |
|     1900 |    1900 |      1900 |            5 |
|     1901 |    1901 |      1901 |            1 |
|     1901 |    1901 |      1901 |            2 |
|     1901 |    1901 |      1901 |            3 |
|     1901 |    1901 |      1901 |            4 |
|     1901 |    1901 |      1901 |            5 |
|     1902 |    1902 |      1902 |            1 |
|     1902 |    1902 |      1902 |            2 |
|     1902 |    1902 |      1902 |            3 |
|     1902 |    1902 |      1902 |            4 |
|     1902 |    1902 |      1902 |            5 |
```

Comment: Dear xXx, thanks for the answer. However, i would like to ask how do i loop the number from ACC_YEAR 1900 to 2501 by copying the ACC_YEAR for 5 row and increment the Earned Month + 1 until 5th row. Then on the 6th row,it will be starting at ACC_YEAR 1901 and the the earned_month start from 1 to 5 again.

Comment: @user3260162 what do you mean by loop ? The query mentioned above matches with your expected result. Can you please clarify your problem ?

Comment: Basically, i have ACC_YEAR in which the year is from 1900 - 2501 in my database and the earned_month is 1 to 5. What i need help right now is , based on the ACC_YEAR how i repeat the number. The table that you show is ok. But, what if i want to add ACC_YEAR 1902,1903, 1904 up to 2501 and repeat the earned month 1,2,3,4,5.. Anyway we can write it?

Comment: @user3260162 Can you update your post with the information you're mentioning above? Because the query works for 1902,1093... I updated my answer.

Comment: Don't Loop at all, @user3260162 . If you're looping you're doing it *very* wrong.

Comment: I think if the OP took the time to read about the tally, they'd likely be able to answer this themselves, @xXx . I agree, it's not completely clear.

Comment: sorry i am no really technical person here. Alright, i try to put it simple. I want to define two column which which is ACC_YEAR and EARNED_MONTH. For the ACC_YEAR it will start from 1900 to 2501. As for EARNED_MONTH it will start from 1 to 5.  The output i want to achieve is for each ACC_YEAR, let say 1900 i want to output the earned month 1 to 5. Then, when come to ACC_YEAR 1901, repeat the earned month from 1 to 5. Then when the ACC_YEAR reach 2501, repeat the earned month from 1 to 5. In conclusion, based on ACC_YEAR i want to output earned month from 1-5.

Comment: Still sounds like you want a Tally. Like I said, take the time to read the article I suggested.